# How to set a variable from package.json script using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, npm

The problem I am currently having is that we have a script in our package.json set to run single test files using the following syntax:

```
"singleTest": "mocha tests/$MATCH"
```

However, when I attempt to run this in Windows 10 with Powershell I use the following command and get the error shown:

```
$env:MATCH="01HOME-01FC-T01.js" && npm run singleTest

Error: No test files found: "tests/$MATCH"
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! selenium-js-example@2.0.0 singleTest: `mocha tests/$MATCH`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the selenium-js-example@2.0.0 singleTest script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It seems as if it is not setting the file name to the variable MATCH at all. I would really appreciate if someone can shed some light on what am I doing wrong or what would be the proper way to run this using Powershell 7.1.

Comment: It's not entirely obvious what you're trying to do here, like what is the purpose of `env:$Match`? How does that connect to npm? And how are you reading `"singleTest": "mocha tests/$MATCH"`? Is that the contents of the .js file or somewhere else? Generally PowerShell will not resolve varialbes contained in files like that, they will just be imported as straight strings.

Comment: @PMental sorry for not being clear enough in my question. Basically what I am trying to do is assign the name of the file dynamically to the variable "$MATCH" through the command line and then run the test. The "singleTest" script will try to run the file assigned to $MATCH. In Linux one would run this simply by typing "MATCH=filename.js npm run singleTest, but with Powershell in Windows I'm not sure how I can do it.

Comment: The default shell npm utilizes to run scripts on windows is `cmd`, so try changing your npm script to: `"singleTest": "mocha tests/%MATCH%"`, then run the following command: `$env:MATCH="01HOME-01FC-T01.js"; npm run singleTest`

Answer (score -1):

You can chain commands in Powershell by using semicolon. You cannot use && like in bash.

```bash
$env:MATCH="01HOME-01FC-T01.js"; npm run singleTest
```